# Variance of the mean in case of a quadratic trend

Tags: python, prediction, standard-deviation, trend, nonlinear

Please allow me to use Python code to put my question across. Suppose we want to model a variable using either a linear or a quadratic trend:

```
import numpy as np  
yields = [0.613103, ..., 1.465184]  
years  = [2008, ..., 2019]
```

As offset we'll use *1965* for the years - also for calculating the mean year:

`x_ = (np.sum(years) / len(years)) - offset`

The linear and the quadratic model will look like this, with x = year - offset

```
def model1(xdata, coeffs): return [coeffs[0] + coeffs[1]\*x for x in xdata]  
def model2(xdata, coeffs): return [coeffs[0] + coeffs[1]\*x + coeffs[2]*(x**2) for x in xdata]
```

The residuals relative to the observations are squared and the sum is minimised. Thus we obtain the optimal coefficients "coeffsopt". Then we can calculate the trend values as well as the errors:

```
trendvalues = model([yr - offset for yr in years], coeffsopt)  
errors = np.array(yields) - np.array(trendvalues)
```

The residual standard deviation can be calculated as follows:

```
ResStd = sqrt(np.sum(errors**2) / df)  \# with df = 2 for linear and 3 for quadratic model
```

I know that in case of a linear model, the standard error of prediction for the mean for year 2019 can be calculated as follows:

```
num = (2019 - offset - x_)**2  
denom = np.sum((np.array(years) - offset - x_)**2)  
StdErrPredMean = ResStd * sqrt((1 / len(years)) + (num / denom))
```

**Questions:**

- How could I also calculate the standard error of prediction for the mean for a quadratic model???
- Is it the same as calculating the standard error of prediction for a multivariate case with x-squared being just another variable which has some interaction with x???

Comment: Welcome to the site, I have formatted your question to be more readable.

Comment: Re your question at the end: yes.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=quadratic+regression+ for myriad examples.